# How to postpone all notifications?

Tags: notifications, 6.0-marshmallow

I want to avoid seeing any e-mails, messages, or other notifications in order to focus for a few hours. But I also use my phone to listen to music, so I can't simply put my phone in another room or otherwise avoid looking at it. Is there a way (preferably but not necessarily on an unrooted phone) to turn off all notifications so they don't appear in the status bar until notifications are turned on? It might be acceptable if notifications never show up when you turn notifications back on, but not ideal.

I use a Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 6.0.1.

Some things I've tried and didn't do what I wanted:

- **Do Not Disturb Mode**: prevents notifications from ringing or vibrating your phone, but doesn't prevent them from appearing in the status bar.
- **Settings > Notifications**: doesn't seem to offer an option to turn off notifications for ALL apps (and them turn them back on), only for each app.
- **Airplane Mode**: effectively postpones all notifications until disabled, but prevents me from streaming music.

Comment: Have you tried [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff)?

Comment: Or [XNotifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Taptigo.Xposed.XNotifications)? It has a "mute" feature for "silent hours". Not sure if it "caches" them to pop-up when mute time ends, though.

Comment: Airplain mode would be pretty much the simplest choise - no network - no chats - no emails - no notifications

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and I've only just started using this app called [Offtime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.offtime.kit)

It has everything you're looking for.
Just select how long you don't want to be disturbed and that's it. You can whitelist the apps you really need to access. Leave the Wi-Fi on. And it'll intercept all the other notifications and swipe them away and show you a summary once the session ends.

Give it a shot and let me know if it works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this app - "AppBlock - Stay Focused"

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.mobilesoft.appblock

It allows you to block certain apps for a specified time period and you can schedule in advance.